# How to convert Java primitive to boxed type in IntelliJ Structural Replace

Tags: java, intellij-idea, structural-search

I'm trying to use IntelliJ Structural Search and Replace to overload a suite of setter methods with `Optional` variants. This needs to honour that the target value may be primitive (e.g. `boolean` to `Optional<Boolean>`). Here's the core part of the conversion:

Search:

```
public static void set($BType$ $BName$, $VType$ $VName$) {
    $body$; // 0 - infinity
}
```

Replacement:

```
public static void set($BType$ $BName$, java.util.Optional<$VTypeMightBeBoxed$> $VName$) {
    $VName$.ifPresent(v -> set($BName$, v));
}
public static void set($BType$ $BName$, $VType$ $VName$) {
    $body$;
}
```

I'm a bit stuck on the PSI Groovy script required to generate `$vTypeMightBeBoxed`

PS. This is mostly caused by the total lack of editor-assistance when adding these scripts! Not what is expected from Jetbrains!

Comment: What is an `Optional<Boolean>` supposed to be, a "yes/no/maybe"-thingy? Do you have any chance of using a more precise enum-type with three options instead?

Comment: It's meant to be an example :) `boolean` could be `int`, `int[]`, `String`, `List<String>` or `MyClass`. It's about using SSR to blindly add alternative setter methods that accept Optionals, not nasty tri-state logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script for `$VTypeMightBeBoxed$` like this should work:

```
import com.intellij.psi.*
def x = VType.getType()
if (x instanceof PsiPrimitiveType) {
  return x.getBoxedTypeName();
} else {
  return VType.getText();
}
```

But watch out, your replacement will generate red code when there are multiple of these set methods with the same name in a class: the methods will have the same erasure.

Comment: That was more or less where I've gotten to though much neater. I did find two 'red methods' where someone had added the setter manually. All good though - fixing two compilation issues is much cheaper than adding 200 methods.